# generic (non-static) method with Class parameter for typesafety, how does it work?

Tags: java, class, generics, types, static

this is my code, Control is an swt-ui-widget, the method find should return a component with the type passed in "clazz". I know how to do this with static methods, but it doesn't work if it's an instance method.

```
package org.uilib.swt.templating;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;

public class Component<T extends Control> {

    public final String name;
    public final T control;

    public Component(String name, T control) {
        this.name = name;
        this.control = control;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public T getControl() {
        return control;
    }

    public Component<E> find(String query, Class<E extends Control> clazz) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

i want to do the following:

```
Component<Button> x = this.find("asd", Button.class);
```

Comment: It doesn't compile if that's what you mean?  Making the methods static wouldn't help it compile.  The problem you have is that T might not be a Button so your find() is not going to return the right type.

Comment: Are the 2 wildcards supposed to be the same type?

Comment: @Peter: True, i will need a cast in the method.

Comment: @Stefan: No, they can be different.

Comment: You need to know the type at runtime to create an instance of it.  You can't use `T` or cast the object because it has to be that type (and thus not need casting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need the following generic method:

```
public <E extends Control> Component<E> find(String query, Class<E> clazz) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public <T extends Component> T find(String query, Class<T> clazz) {
        return null;
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is correct. Hes searching by the class of a Control element not a Component.

Comment: Yeah, my initial question was a bit unclear, i updated it now.